# How to check perl version

Tags: perl, version

the default Perl version installed on my machine is the 5.8.7. 
When I run my script internally switch to another perl version (v5.10.1) doing this:

```
  my $perl_5_10 = "/opt/perl_5.10.1/bin";
  $ENV{'PATH'}  = $perl_5_10 ":" . $ENV{'PATH'};
```

Now, I have to check the perl version, and I do:

```
   ## PERL: need perl version >= 5.10!
   if ($] < 5.010000)
   {
     ## VERSION ERROR!
   }

   my $perl_cmd = "perl --version";
   my $perl_str=`$perl_cmd`;
   print "PERL VERSION = " . $perl_str;   ## this clearly print 5.10.1
```

it return error as the version used is 5.8.7 and that's pretty normal as I ran my script with that version. But my problem is:

how can I check that the new perl version is >= 5.10.1 ?

Comment: Try using [`$^V`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Comment: Put `use 5.010001` into the script that needs to run in the newer version.

Comment: The main script I know will start with the version 5.8 but after being launched I switch to 5.10. At thet point I have to check if I switched correctly (or the new version is available) ....

Comment: What does it mean `to switch`?

Comment: That my script is launched with a perl version, then I add to the env variable another perl version (see code) 5.10 and then from this script I run another script. But first need to check that the new perl version is available ... That's all

Comment: Why don't you run everything under Perl 5.10?

Comment: How are you calling the 'another script'? What syntax do you use? backticks, system-call or something else??

Answer (score 7):

The first 3 decimals are the subversion, and second 3 decimals are revision.  Therefore use

```
if ($] >= 5.010001)
{
    ## We're all good.  Greater than 5.10.1
}
```

I primarily use 5.18.2, and therefore my `$]` equals `5.018002`.

For alternative methods check out [`perlvar $PERL_VERSION or $^V`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) and [`use VERSION`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html)

Comment: Mmmh, my problem is that i started my script with a perl version (5.8) and then set the env var to perl version 5.10 but will be valid just for the perl script I run (into my script) after that ... So I think my unique chance is to run perl -version and parse it.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I check that the new perl version is >= 5.10.1 ?

You gave an answer in your question:

```perl
my $perl_cmd = "perl --version";
my $perl_str=`$perl_cmd`;
print "PERL VERSION = " . $perl_str;   ## this clearly print 5.10.1
```

Since your change can only alter the version of newly started `perl` instances, you have to run a new `perl` to check, as you did above.

Comment: One of the problems with this is that you don't know if `perl` is the same `perl` that you are running. For that, you would use `$^X` to get the path to the current `perl`. But, you don't need to run an external command because the `$^V` variable gives you this info.

Comment: The querist doesn't want to _know if `perl` is the same perl that you are running._ On the contrary, he wants to run another version.